# Is there way to make stuct, contains inner references?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

How can I do something like that:

```rust
    struct Parsed<'a> {
        bytes: Vec<u8>,
        h: &'a [u8]
    }
    impl<'a> Parsed<'a> {
        fn new(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
            let h = bytes.as_slice();
            Parsed {
                bytes,
                h,
            }
        }
    }
```

I need it for parsing messages with nom from tcp streams without copy objects.
Cause I know size of messages, I can prepare some byte array for nom, but cannot return parsed messages to caller. I think it's a good idea to place buffer inside message struct, but it fail with rust borrow-checker :'(

Borrow checker says as follows:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `bytes`
   --> src/main.rs:217:13
    |
216 |               let h = bytes.as_slice();
    |                       ----- `bytes` is borrowed here
217 | /             Parsed {
218 | |                 bytes,
219 | |                 h,
220 | |             }
    | |_____________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `bytes` because it is borrowed
   --> src/main.rs:218:17
    |
214 |       impl<'a> Parsed<'a> {
    |            -- lifetime `'a` defined here
215 |           fn new(bytes: Vec<u8>) -> Self {
216 |               let h = bytes.as_slice();
    |                       ----- borrow of `bytes` occurs here
217 | /             Parsed {
218 | |                 bytes,
    | |                 ^^^^^ move out of `bytes` occurs here
219 | |                 h,
220 | |             }
    | |_____________- returning this value requires that `bytes` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Comment: You should either store only `Vec<u8>` (if you want `Parsed` to own the data) or only `&a [u8]` (if you want `Parsed<'a>` to reference the data owned elsewhere).